# Use of multiple ... function arguments in R

Tags: r

Quick question I was thinking about, I understand if you have one argument in your function with varying parameters, you can use `...` and move on. But if you have several arguments with varying parameters, how would that work?

**Example:**

```
d <- data.frame(alpha=1:3, beta=4:6, gamma=7:9, type = c("okay", "no", "yes")) 
rownames(d) <- d[,4]

test <- function(...){
  x <- c(...)
  y <- d[x,]
  z <- y$alpha

  print(z)
}

test("okay","no")
```

But, in the situation where I might have a second dataframe that I want to include in my function:

```
d2 <- data.frame(one=2:4, two=10:12, three=20:22, label = c("blue","yellow","red"))
rownames(d2) <- d[,4]

test2 <- function(..., ...){
  x <- c(...)
  y <- d[x,]
  z <- y$alpha

  x2 <- c(...) ## ? 
}
```

How would I tell R that the first `...` argument is for df, and the second `...` argument is for df2?

EDIT -

the function call for the test2 would ideally be: `test2("okay","no","blue","red")` where the first two arguments are for df, and the other two for df2. I'm just not sure how to tell R how to differentiate between these arguments.

Comment: Arguments can only be used once each within a function declaration; in this case, you are repeating it. I'm not entirely clear what you are needing to do in your examples. Please include an example of you actually calling your two test functions and (even with this trivial example) what you think the output should be.

Comment: (There is a section on the ellipses at http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html)

Comment: How would you specify the difference when entering the parameters? A simple alternative (if the structure is really necessary in the first place) is to turn one into a named parameter that takes a list, and use `do.call` to use it as parameters for a function.

Comment: ...or do you just mean able to take a vector? Any parameter can do that; there usually shouldn't be reason to wrap a it in `c` within the function.

Comment: @r2evans I knew I missed something, added function calls!

Comment: Just pass vectors to single parameters: `test2(c("okay","no"), c("blue","red"))`

Comment: Your example code shows sloppy scope. That is, you are reaching out of the function to find the data.frame `d`, something that *will* bite you if you do it frequently. I suggest you make all the data required by the function required as arguments. It is legitimate, for example, do define a function as `function(..., .data)` where you can provide an arbitrary number of arguments, but only the one you explicitly name as `.data` will be used as such.

Comment: Alistaire - thank you! @r2evans - I don't doubt that, but can you give me insight on why dataframes should not be created outside a function?

Comment: During testing or shifting from one dataset to another. For instance, it looks like you are ALWAYS running this function on a specific dataset. Perhaps it takes hours, and you want to test it on a smaller version. Or you want to test it on a different dataset, temporarily. In your case, you have to move variables around to ensure that `d` always has the one of immediate interest. If you provide it explicitly in the function call, there is never any ambiguity of which data you are intending to use. (Don't take this *too* literally: there are times when a little scope-reach may be okay ...)

Comment: Similarly, I often use rmarkdown files for exploratory analysis of my data. In that case, I am often using the same function on different data, whether it be different portions of a single larger table or just different (say) years/locations/whatever. If I move variables around, it's a bit harder to figure out which data is being used in any particular call, whereas with explicit data-as-an-argument, the function call says it all.